# Eclipse CDT, Mingw-w64 g++ not found in PATH

Tags: eclipse, build, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I can't get CDT to resolve MinGW's path, whats odd is that earlier today it was not having this error and CDT was building fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6tNK.png
[image: screenshot]

Windows 7, Eclipse Kepler

If i run g++ manually with cmd it works perfectly fine.
It is definitely included properly in my system variables.
I do not have msys but it shouldn't be needed.
I have restarted eclipse and my computer multiple times and it makes no difference.

I have seen many similar variants of this question and none of them have a working answer.

Edit: I think it is recognizing it as CrossGCC, which technically w64 is, however changing to CrossGCC doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by leaving everything as-is and creating a new project as Cross-GCC.

I resolved two of the four errors in the old project by going to project properties \ C++ general \ Preprocessor Include -> Restore defaults.

Resolved the other two by same place \ providers -> uncheck MinGW, check CrossGCC